# Manipulate a string that is stored in a variable

Tags: bash

I have a script that uses a find command to find some directory names I need but the output has them in the same string and with an extra level of path I don't need. I want to split them, cut out the part I don't need, and add them each to an array.

find command:

```
projects=$(find Un -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'Proj_*')
```

find command result (stored as $projects in the script):

```
Un/Proj_ABCD4 Un/Proj_EF2GH Un/Proj_PG5T3 Un/Proj_MMXCU
```

What I want to put in the array:

```
Proj_ABCD4
Proj_EF2GH
Proj_PG5T3
Proj_MMXCU
```

Comment: Are you sure you need an array? If you just want to loop over them, `for proj in Un/Proj_*/; do ... something with "${proj#Un/}"; done`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `find` for this case:

```
projects=()
cd Un && \
for d in Proj_*/; do
    projects+=( "${d%/}" )
done && \
cd ..
```

Or to exclude symbolic links:

```
projects=()
cd Un && \
for d in Proj_*; do
    [[ -d $d ]] && ! [[ -L $d ]] && projects+=("$d")
done && \
cd ..
```